# How to apply smooth parameter to main effect and interaction separately in mgcv?

Tags: r, mgcv

I use the code below to apply smooth parameter to interaction term only.

```
mgcv::gam(Y ~ s(X1, k=3, sp=-1) + s(X2, k=4, sp=-1) + 
            ti(X1, X2, k=4, sp=c(1,1)) + X3,
          method = "REML")
```

`k` value is quite small for my model because I just want get very smooth spline curves of variables.

In this code, I tried apply `sp = 1` for interaction term.

Is this correct method to using `sp` option to control smoothness parameter?

And, could I setting the sp parameter values for X1, X2 individually inside `ti()` interaction term? (Like below)

```
ti(X1, X2, k=3, sp=c(0.5, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the first example the marginal smooths for `X1` and `X2` will have their smoothness parameters fixed at the value `1`. In the second example you have a fixed smoothing parameter of `0.5` for the marginal smooth of `X1` and a smoothing parameter of `1` for the marginal smooth of `X2` in the tensor product interaction smooth.